# Bash one-liner way to preserve original pipe output file in presence of a pipe error?

Tags: linux, bash

There are many ways to do this using intermediate files and functions or append/truncate, but I was curious if anyone knows how a one-liner way to express a conditionally non-destructive overwrite like either of:

```
# outfile not touched if script1 fails
script1  > outfile
# outfile not touched if script1 or script2 fails
script1 | script2 > outfile
# or maybe a "lazy >" command, but I'd rather see how bash itself can do this
script1 | script2 | magicproxy outfile
```

where outfile's prior contents remain untouched *if* its pipeline failed to output any valid stream content.

It is okay to mess up outfile if *some* output flows, but not if *no* output flows.

I don't know of anything bash-wise to account for this, as I am fairly certain it does not pend basic file setup related to a pipeline stdout file until it sees output flow. Unless there is a magic set -o lazy option lurking.

So I am looking for a one-liner way to make a pipeline more lazy than eager wrt basic stdout file setup, triggered "on first actual output", using bash conventions.

Comment: You're correct in that the FIFOs are all -- necessarily -- set up *before* the subprocesses are started. Can't be any other way -- after the `execve` calls are done, there's no way for the parent process to synchronously change where the FDs point.

Comment: The conventional thing is `script1 | script2 > tempfile && mv tempfile outfile`, albeit with a generated (guaranteed unique) as opposed to constant tempfile name.

Comment: ...that said, something like the `sponge` command from moreutils might be possible to extend into your use case, by adding an option to abort if no contents exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### A Quick Note For Future Readers

The original question here asked only about waiting for at least one line of output to make it through the pipeline before modifying the output file. This is *not the same* as ensuring that the pipeline exits with a nonzero status before overwriting the destination file, but the section "depending on pipeline success" has been added with details on just that approach.

---

#### Depending on pipeline success

Unfortunately, this one's not so easy to write as a one-liner.

```
shopt -s pipefail # fail if any component of a pipeline doesn't succeed

tempfile=$(mktemp "$1".XXXXXX)
if script1 | script2 >"$tempfile"; then
  mv -- "$tempfile" "$1"
else
  rm -f -- "$tempfile"
fi
```

An obvious approach is to use `eval`, but this requires great care to avoid security bugs:

```
# DANGER: command_source *must* be a constant string; MUST NOT substitute argument values
#         directly into source -- instead, refer to variables from that string.
eval_to_output_file() {
  local command_source destfile tempfile retval
  command_source=$1
  destfile=$2
  tempfile=$(mktemp -- "$destfile.XXXXXX")
  if eval "$command_source" >"$tempfile"; then
    mv -- "$tempfile" "$destfile"
  else
    retval=$?
    rm -f -- "$tempfile"
    return "$retval"
  fi
}
```

...usage as:

```
# CRITICAL that script argument is single-quoted, and all arguments expanded by eval
# ...otherwise, expansions can perform code injection.
eval_to_output_file 'script1 "$arg1" | script2 "$arg2"' outfile
```

More safely, the pipeline could be encapsulated in a function:

```
# Safer alternative to eval_to_output_file
# Requires that a pipeline be encapsulated into a function
run_to_output_file() {
  local destfile retval
  destfile=$1; shift
  tempfile=$(mktemp -- "$destfile.XXXXXX")
  if "$@" >"$tempfile"; then
    mv -- "$tempfile" "$destfile"
  else
    retval=$?
    rm -f -- "$tempfile"
    return "$retval"
  fi
}

# example of a function running your pipeline
# note that arguments are passed through by the above
myfunc() (          # myfunc() ( ) instead of myfunc() { } means execute in a subshell
  shopt -s pipefail # because we're in a subshell, this won't propagate out
  script1 "$1" | script2 "$2"
)

run_to_output_file outfile myfunc arg1 arg2
```

---

#### Waiting only for the first line

```
magicproxy() {
  [[ $1 ]] || { echo "Usage: magicproxy filename" >&2; return 1; }

  if IFS= read -r first_line; then
    cat <(printf '%s\n' "$first_line") - >"$1"
  fi
}
```

Note that this means that your output file will exist with partial contents at some point.

---

#### Renaming after the entire stream is complete

```
magicproxy() {
  [[ $1 ]] || { echo "Usage: magicproxy filename" >&2; return 1; }

  local tempfile
  tempfile=$(mktemp -- "$1.XXXXXX") || return
  if cat >"$tempfile" && [[ -s "$tempfile" ]]; then
    mv -- "$tempfile" "$1"
  else
    rm -f -- "$tempfile"
  fi
}
```

...will work with your proposed pipeline:

```
script1 | script2 | magicproxy outfile
```

---

That said, if you're on a GNU system and the restrictive permissions used by `mktemp` don't work for you, you might also want to add:

```
# give your temporary file the same permissions as your destination
chmod --reference="$1" -- "$tempfile"
```

...before the `mv`.

Comment: Yes perfect! This is better done explicitly anyway due to the importance of clearly showing update avoidance cases.

Comment: Nice!  Detail question: if I'm reading correctly, both `magicproxy` versions will overwrite the named file if something earlier in the pipe produces output, but then fails after that (as opposed to failing before producing any output).  Am I right, or am I missing something?  Would `magicproxy` need to be called when `pipefail` is set to prevent writing `$1` in that case?

Comment: @cxw, ...so, the OP originally asked only about the no-output error case; covering anything else was a later extension. The tricky thing, here, is that there's no mechanism for the last entry in a pipeline to know how things earlier in that pipeline exited (after all, they're all running concurrently -- and moreover, in `A|B`, if `A` closes its stdout and waits for a while before exiting, then `B` can actually exit *before* `A` does, thus, while A doesn't *have* an exit status at all!)

Comment: @cxw, ...hence the first "depending on pipeline success" section not using magicproxy at all, and only permitting one-liner use with ugliness such as `eval`.

Comment: @cxw, ...well -- ugliness such as `eval`, or a function encapsulating the pipeline. You've actually encouraged me to extend with an answer demonstrating the latter.

Comment: Nice (again)!  I don't think I've seen `if "$@"` before.  Thanks for the edit!